# So I have a jnlp file error MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jar>href]

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Here is the error in full

```
MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jar>href]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.getRequiredURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.handleResourceElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2$1.visitElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitChildrenElements(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2.visitElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitElements(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.buildResourcesDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here is my file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jnlp PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc//DTD JNLP Descriptor 6.0//EN"           "http://java.sun.com/dtd/JNLP-6.0.dtd">
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="https://ws2.bwvoip.net/servlet/jws" href="receptionist.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Receptionist</title>
    <vendor>Zayo Enterprise Networks</vendor>
    <icon href="customization/receptionist/images/splash.jpg" kind="splash"/>
    <icon href="customization/receptionist/images/z-window-icon.png" kind="shortcut"/>
    <offline-allowed/> 

  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
<update check="always" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
  <java version="1.6+"/>
  <property name="ksessionid" value="EE5CD289475BD77CA759D670D79C81813AD4A293"/>
  <property name="userid" value="3032853221"/>
  <property name="profileName" value="System"/>
  <property name="timestamp" value="1390868509416"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/BWReceptionist.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false" main="true"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/activation.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/BWJFC.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/bwswing.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/common.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/hsqldb.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/jRegistryKey.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/locale.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/mail.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/plugin.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/xml.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/jnlp.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/bwpersonaldirectory/bwpersonaldirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/bwrdirectory/bwrdirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/bwrmonitoringdirectory/bwrmonitoringdirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/bwspeeddialdirectory/bwspeeddialdirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/ldapclientdirectory/ldapclientdirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/plugins/outlookdirectory/outlookdirectory.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/conf/profile.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/user/1/84/184332379/receptionist/conf/usersettings.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false" part="settings"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/jaxb-api.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/jaxb-impl.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <jar href="customization/receptionist/lib/activation.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
      <nativelib href="customization/receptionist/lib/bwnative.jar?reposAddr=199.199.3.1;reposPort=80;reposRoot=%2FFileRepos;reposSecure=false"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.broadsoft.bwreceptionist.gui.Starter"/>
</jnlp>
```

I cannot se the missing field or syntax error.

This only occurs on java 7u65 and later, works fin with 7u55. I am lost please help.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Make sure your file is really UTF-8 encoded (e.g. with Notepadd++). The problem seems to be your parameters in the urls (at least this is what janela says). Try to replace your questionmarks with &#63; semicolon with &#038; . And fix the other janela stuff (ordering etc.) However I woulnd't bet that janela is correct about the link warnings...